# Encrypt text into image's pixels(online)

Tags: image, encryption, symbols

I tried to search from the question list here, but didn't find what do I need.

Every pixel consists of red, green and blue value, which can get of 256 values, by single, so, summary every pixel can get one of 16 777 216 values.

Imagine, I have a text - "hello", every letter corresponds to its numerical symbol value (0-256 for ascii).

So I have an array of pixels that can be described as a number, and I have a symbols, that do as well. I want to make image, which pixels values will correspond to some text symbols values. 5 symbols - 5 pixel.

Is there any online services, that can do this? Or I should code?

Comment: For each pixel, you have a byte for red, a byte for green and a byte for blue, so you can store 3 ASCII characters in a pixel if you want to. But... what's the point of this please?

Comment: Google search "online steganography tool"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- h=ASCII code 104
- e=ASCII code 101
- l=ASCII code 108
- o=ASCII code 111

So, using **ImageMagick** in Terminal, you can make a 5 pixel wide, greyscale hello image like this:

```
magick -depth 8 xc:"gray(104)" xc:"gray(101)" xc:"gray(108)" xc:"gray(108)" xc:"gray(111)" +append hello.png
```

Don't save as JPEG, it is lossy.

You can dump the pixels like this:

```
magick hello.png txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 5,1,65535,gray
0,0: (26728)  #686868  gray(104)
1,0: (25957)  #656565  gray(101)
2,0: (27756)  #6C6C6C  gray(108)
3,0: (27756)  #6C6C6C  gray(108)
4,0: (28527)  #6F6F6F  gray(111)
```